# How to get the last token of a string by a given separator?

Tags: windows, batch-file

If I have the following string `remotes/origin/rc_1.1.1` and I would like to get just the `rc_1.1.1` part, i.e. get the branch name without `remotes/origin/`, or getting the last string token when tokenizing by forward slash.

How do I do that within a Windows batch file?

Comment: Very simple: `set "last=%string:/=" & set "last=%"`  This method allows a multi-char separator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a standard `for` loop, and use the modifiers for filename and extension. This works because the backward and/or forward slash is treated as a path separator with the modifier.

Example:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "string=remotes/origin/rc_1.1.1"
For %%G In ("%string%") Do Echo %%~nxG

Set "string=remotes\origin\rc_1.1.1"
For %%G In ("%string%") Do Echo %%~nxG

Pause
```

Please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?` and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to see its usage information, and the available modifiers, to learn more.